# Checkstyle is unable to satisfy suppressions filter, why is that?

Tags: java, gradle, checkstyle

I'm using gradle and checkstyle and suppressions are being completely ignored.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
        "-//Checkstyle//DTD SuppressionFilter Configuration 1.2//EN"
        "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/suppressions_1_2.dtd">

<suppressions>
    <suppress files="[/\\]*/build/generated-test-avro-java[/\\]" checks=".*"/>
    <suppress files="[/\\]*/build/generated-main-avro-java[/\\]" checks=".*"/>
    <suppress files="[/\\]*/build/*" checks=".*"/>
</suppressions>
```

```
    checkstyle {
        toolVersion = "${checkstyleVersion}"
        config = rootProject.resources.text.fromFile("etc/checkstyle/rules.xml")
        configProperties = [ "suppressionFile" : project(':').file('etc/checkstyle/suppressions.xml')]
        showViolations = true
        ignoreFailures = false

        // Strict build failures
        maxWarnings = 0
    }
```

The filepath is correct. I'm using the google checkstyle XML off master (latest).

Why would this happen?

#### result from the ignored path

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you put the configuration in the default location, as shown here? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/checkstyle_plugin.html#sec:checkstyle_project_layout

Comment: Did you have any luck? I am facing a similar problem :(

Comment: @GiorgosK. yes, actually I just placed it in the default location as suggested above. I avoided getting fancy with custom paths.